# Unity3d sometimes game ending condition don't trigger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-debugging

I have a simple action-arcade game with player and multiple enemies. I have wrote a game such that when all enemies are dead the level ends. I keep track of enemies bu having a central GameplayController which has a static int called enemiescount. I increment this value at in the awake method of a script attached to each of my enemies object, and when and enemy dies I call a method to this gameplay controller named CountEnemies which decrement the variable and if it equals to zero ends the level.

Here is the code to my CountEnemies methid called by the enemies class:

```
    GameplayController.instance.CountEnemies();
```

where instance just returns the singleton instance of the GameplayController.

Here's the code to my CountEnemies method:

```
    Debug.Log("Inside Count Enemies");
    Debug.Log("Count Enemies before: " + enemiesCount);
    enemiesCount--;
    Debug.Log("Count Enemies after: " + enemiesCount);

    if (enemiesCount == 0) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy Count is equal to zero");
        //Complete Level
    }
    Debug.Log("End Count Enemies");
```

Now the issue is it used to work most of the times. But randomly at somepoint when I try to run it on mobile it fails to end the level. I tried multiple times to diagnose the issue but everytime I run it on PC it seems to run flawlessly and secndly even at some rare instance it did trigger the problem, all I can found out was that even though the CountEnemies was called at every turn, through some strange cause the enemies count variable seems to not have decremented or may have been incremented.

I have keep track of the code through Visual studio codemap and references and only in place of the Awake method did I increment the variable. Please help me sort this out or atleast suggest me how to debug it like whenever a value of this variable updates the attached debugger lets me know or something.

Comment: When does the method get called? Is it when an enemy gets killed in an OnDeath() method of some sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I increment this value at in the awake method of a script attached to each of my enemies object, and when and enemy dies I call a method to this gameplay controller named CountEnemies which decrement the variable and if it equals to zero ends the level.

This may be your problem.

Awake may be getting called multiple times and causing issues where the count is being increased too much, causing the count to be delinked from the actual number of enemies remaining.

A better solution might be to have a script that periodically checks the amount of GameObjects with your component that currently exist in the Scene. Alternatively, you can check how many enemies are remaining when you are disposing of a currently existing enemy (You don't want it part of `Update` or `FixedUpdate`).

[`FindObjectsOfType`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) is probably the call you want to make. You can use it to find all objects with your type. If you don't have too many objects on the world at once, the cost of using this method won't matter too much.

Basically, the point is that increasing a static number is not the correct approach, because it can easily spiral out of control.

Comment: General programming principle I like is "Single source of truth". Never have, for instance, a Switch class that has both "bool isTurnedOn" and "bool isTurnedOnByPlayer" - There should always only be ONE way to get the particular number or piece of data you need in your code. At the most, cache a derived value ahead of the calculation (only if it turns out you need to for performance) and tightly control access to that cache.

Comment: Well put, I have seen 'GameManager' classes in several tutorials and walkthrough videos for Unity and I have started implementing similar logic in my projects as well. In this case, number of enemies the scene had loaded over its life would be kept as a property here.

Comment: @Polantris
Alternatively, you can check how many enemies are remaining when you are disposing of a currently existing enemy (You don't want it part of Update or FixedUpdate).

What do you exactly mean by not in Update? I'm checking for the condition to dispose enemy inside the Update method and then I call Destroy on its gameobject. Specifically speaking to my case wouldn't it be kay if I call FindObjectsOfType in the CountEnemies method of my GameplayController?

Secondly, let's say if I have around 15 enemies at once would it be costly to call it or not?

Comment: What I mean is that you don't want to have the actual monster count check in every single `Update` or `FixedUpdate` because it's an expensive call. When you're in the middle of disposing of an enemy, before you delete it, also check to see if there are any other monsters left. If there are no other monsters left, you can end the stage normally. You can do this in [`OnDestroy`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html), if you Destroy your enemies immediately.